# Need help Porting windows service (asmx) from windows server to Linux (mono)

Tags: asp.net, iis, mono, asmx

I am trying to port small part of my application ( activation server) a windows service (asmx) from Windows VPS to Linux platform

After searching on internet and reading in many post, i have decided to hack my way using [Mono-Project](http://www.mono-project.com/)

I was able to find the tutorial on how to run aspx files and other things on different posts..but i am not able to find any documentation on how to run or Port my already developed and running service from Windows server (ISS+ASMX+MSSQL)  to Linux ( Ubuntu 14.04 + mono + Apache + MySQL)

can some one share their view on best-way-to-acheive the task or some documentation links somewhere

Also , i would like your opinion on whether i should stick with my decision to go on with Mono or i should consider other framework

Thanks,